# What is the equivalent of "site:www.example.com searchterm" in Firefox/DuckDuckGo

Tags: firefox, search

Previously I used Chromium/Google Search as my browser/search engine combo. When I did that I could type the following into the address bar to limit my search to a specific site:

```
site:www.example.com searchterm
```

Now I am using Firefox/DuckDuckGo instead. When I type the same command into the address bar I get this error:

> Problem loading page
>
> The address wasn't understood
>
> Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (site) isn't associated with any program.
>
> You might need to install other software to open this address.

If I type the `site:...` command into DuckDuckGo directly, it works. How can I make Firefox recognise the `site:` prefix as a command, OR what is the equivalent command in Firefox?

(I would strongly prefer to use the address bar rather than the search bar.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the tokens:

```
searchterm site:www.example.com
```

By putting `word:word` at the *beginning*, Firefox assumes that you're typing a protocol and hostname.

Answer (score 1):

Add `?` in front of the query to workaround this problem related to Firefox.

Example:
`?site:www.example.com searchterm`

Comment: this works (thanks!) - I picked bahamat's answer just out of personal preference

Comment: Even Firefox updated couples of time, it still cannot handle those queries gracefully while Chrome can.